# How do you create a list which is not itemized or enumerated?

Tags: lists

Stupid question, but how do you make a list on this form?

[image]

I'm only used to making list which is itemized, enumerated and so on.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can get a list without itemization by using the description list in the enumitem package. So for example:

```
\usepackage{enumitem} 

\begin{document}

\begin{description}[leftmargin=!,labelwidth=3em]
    \item[$C^{gen}_{gis}$] Investment cost for generation etc.
    \item[$C^{tran}_{lis}$] Investment cost for transmission etc.
\end{description}

\end{document}
```

will generate:

[image]

You can play around with the labelwidth to get the desired whitespace.

Comment: To clarify: You don't actually need enumitem for the description list, but you do need it for the leftmargin and labelwidth options. Additionally, if you want to remove the vertical separation, you can add the option noitemsep.